# Read a large JSON file and process in Java

Tags: java, json

Iam new to JSON and i need help in reading a large json file which is really huge and it contains pair of name and value in a array .. i need to get this all name and value from this file in my java code and need to perform operations . Can someone give me suggestions on how to read such a big file and store the contents in java code to process it further.

Comment: [Here you are](http://bit.ly/19VysSk), user3161879, enjoy,

Comment: this example should do
http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: It all depends to how your JSON is organized. In one application, I used recursion to find all JSONObjects that fit a desired structure (shared the same key). What operations are you trying to accomplish would help us as well. And by your definition of "big", you are asking for optimizations but without details, we can only guess.